# Does a bufferedreader wrapped around a file reader gets its file pointer from the filereader?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, file-pointer

I have a method like so:

```
public void LoadFromFile(){
String record;
try{
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("Friends.txt");  
        BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(reader);
        while((record = bin.readLine()) != null){
             //do some stuff
        }
        clientinfo = homeAddress.LoadFromFile(reader);
```

The method homeAddress.LoadFromFile(reader) as called above is in another class and is as follows:

```
public String[] LoadFromFile(FileReader areader){
String record;
    try{
        BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(areader);
        while((record = bin.readLine()) != null){
             //do some stuff
            }
        }
        bin.close();
        bin = null;
```

My question is, I'm using the same FileReader throughout, so when I wrap a BufferedReader around it, does the BufferedReader use the file pointer (where to start reading from) from the FileReader?

And does the first BufferedReader update the file pointer so that the second BufferedReader knows where to start from?

Comment: What you can do, is passing the bufferedreader stored in bin, instead of the filereader object

Answer (score 2):

The key here is the word "buffered". No, you can't assume that the `BufferedReader` in the second `LoadFromFile` will pick up exactly where the `BufferedReader` in the caller left off. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

> Reads text from a character-input stream, **buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading** of characters, arrays, and lines.

*(my emphasis)*

That means the `BufferedReader` will read ahead in the file and hold that data in its buffer. So the second `BufferedReader` will pick up with the first character unread by the first — so you may well have a gap between what you've consumed from the first `BufferedReader` and what you will consume from the second.

Instead: Pass the `BufferedReader` into the second method, changing its signature accordingly.

In general, its signature was already a bit off. It shouldn't need to know or care whether it's reading from a file or some other kind of stream; all it needs to know is that it's reading from a `BufferedReader` (since it relies on `readLine`).

---

Side note: In your code, if an exception occurs while reading, you won't have an opportunity to clean up the non-JVM resources allocated by the readers (in particular, the `FileReader`). This is where try-with-resources is really helpful:

```
try (
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("Friends.txt");  
    BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(reader);
) {
    while((record = bin.readLine()) != null){
         //do some stuff
    }
    clientinfo = homeAddress.LoadFromFile(reader);
```

There, even when an exception occurs in `readLine`, the readers are cleaned up.

Comment: I'm reading the question of OP in a way he would be interested to continue where first bufferedreader left off, not neccessarily starting from the beginning, so even if reset would be implemented it might not help.

Comment: @eis: Well, the first block reads all the way to the end (until `readLine` returns `null`) before passing off to the next method, so I assumed he/she would want to start at the beginning. But it's an assumption, and so could be wrong. :-)

Comment: I assumed `// do some stuff` might have `break` in it. Otherwise the question doesn't make that much sense to me.

Comment: @eis your correct, The first BufferedReader in the caller has a break when it reaches a line with the text "###" which I mistakenly truncated for this question

Comment: @ArielKropp: I've added a bit to the end of the answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the [source code of BufferedReader](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedReader.java#l312) that it has an internal variable `nextChar` for the index of next character to be read, so unless you either store the variable yourself or pass around the bufferedreader instance, the "pointer" will not carry on to next call.

This is simple enough to test:

Friends.txt:

```
foo
bar
```

Code:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileReadingTest {
    @Test
    public void LoadFromFile() throws IOException {
        String record;
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("Friends.txt");
            BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(reader);
            while ((record = bin.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("1: read " + record);
                break;
            }
            LoadFromFile(reader);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException foo) {
            System.out.println("file not found from " + new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    public void LoadFromFile(FileReader areader) {
        String record;
        try {
            BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(areader);
            while ((record = bin.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("2: read " + record);
            }
            bin.close();
            bin = null;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
1: read foo

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So the second reader won't even get a chance to read, even if first reading didn't finish. Also, if you introduce bin.close() after the first reading, the second reading will throw `java.io.IOException: Stream closed`.

As suggested in the comments, if you want to carry on reading on the second method where first one left off, simplest way would be passing around the same bufferedreader instance. You'll have to be careful with freeing the resources at the right time then.

Comment: Ok I follow - is there a way for me to stop the first bufferedreader and continue where I left off with the second bufferedreader?

Comment: @ArielKropp simplest way might be just to pass the same bufferedreader instance around. Another alternative is to store the amount of characters read on a variable, close the reader altogether, reopen, and call skip skip(amountOfChars) before your first new read. It does sound to me you'd really want to use the same bufferedreader.